# Gradle: Exclude file from Android assets folder

Tags: android, gradle, assets, build.gradle

Please, do you know a way how to exclude some file from Android project assets folder before  multiple assets folders are merged or during the merge?

For example:

```
android {
  sourceSets {
    main {
      assets.srcDirs = [fileTree(dir: 'assets1', exclude: 'myfile.txt'), 'assets2'] // does not work
      assets.exclude 'assets1/myfile.txt' // does not work
      assets.exclude '**/*.txt' // does not work
      assets.exclude '*.txt' // does not work
    }
  }

  packagingOptions {
    exclude 'assets1/myfile.txt' // does not work
    exclude '**/*.txt' // does not work
    exclude '*.txt' // does not work either
  }


  aaptOptions {
    ignoreAssetsPattern "myfile.txt" // does not work
  }
}
```

Comment: FYI: `assets.srcDirs = [fileTree(dir: 'assets1', exclude: 'myfile.txt'), 'assets2']` does not work.

Comment: Did you find a solution to this? Having the same issue with some assets file from a jar dependency

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's not possible at the moment.

The `packagingOptions` feature does not apply to Android resources or assets.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try to experiment with dependency on Copy task or FileTree  first before I'll give it up...

Answer (score 24):

I run into the same problem and it seems adding a "!" works to indicate the file should be excluded:

```
aaptOptions {
    ignoreAssetsPattern "!myfile.txt" 
}
```

"assets.exclude" might work also by adding a "!" but I haven't tested it...

Comment: use `*` for wide char, and use `:` to split patterns. like: **"!*.txt:!*.rtf"**

Comment: ! indicate about suppressing warning. Docs: https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/6d2c0e5/tools/aapt2/Files.h#88

Comment: Not sure if the docs you mention are related or wrong? I just double-checked and the '!' does indeed ignore the assets. I am aware it's odd, but that's just how it seems to be implemented.

Answer (score 10):

I think this should do what you want:

```
android {
    aaptOptions {
        ignoreAssetsPattern "myfile.txt"
    }
}
```

**Source:** http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide#TOC-aapt-options

Comment: Cool, thanks, I will try that and accept your answer accordingly.

Comment: No, this also does not work. The error about duplicate files is thrown during ``mergeAssets`` stage while I think that ``aaptOption`` is applied during package stage.

Comment: Ok, I see... sorry them :/

Answer (score 7):

we can delete files/folders after build.gradle has finished its internal task of merging all assets .

## android.applicationVariants.all { variant ->  }

this is the loop where many android build tasks(in groovy language) are offered.

so in this case
mergeAssets.doLast is the groovy task where we can perform delete operations.

here i used code to delete a zip file and images folder

tested on Android 3.1.4

hope it helps

```
android.applicationVariants.all { variant ->

if (variant.buildType.name == 'release') {

    variant.mergeAssets.doLast {
        println("deleting item.zip', 'images/**' from variant")
        delete(fileTree(dir: variant.mergeAssets.outputDir, includes: ['item.zip', 'images/**']))
    }
 }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
export ANDROID_AAPT_IGNORE="ignoreAssetsPatternThatActuallyWorks"
./gradlew assembleDebug
```

It's the only way to influence the `mergeDebugAssets` step (code [found here](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/com.android.tools/sdk-common/24.0.1/com/android/ide/common/res2/DataSet.java#514)).

Filed [a bug](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=161356) about this.

Answer (score 0):

just use `bash`

```
zip -d xx.jar xxx.txt
```

to remove duplicated file from jar file

Answer (score 0):

To protect assets folder information If the `html` file is either `css` or `js`, the easiest way is to:
Write your code in the `html editor` first, and then enter it in a `Java class` as follows :

```
 public class Content{
    public static final String  myContent ="<!DOCTYPE html> ... </html> "
```

And then call through the `loadDataWithBaseURL` method

```
 webView.loadDataWithBaseURL(null,Content.myContent, "text/html" , "UTF-8" ,null);
```

And you can call  `js` and `css` in html code :

```
 ...
 <head>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" 
  href="file:///android_asset/css/custom.css" /> 
 <script src="file:///android_asset/js/code.jquery.js"></script>                                                                                   
</head>
```