# How to exclude certain files from Android Studio gradle builds?

Tags: android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

I am using Android Studio with Google Drive, which makes hidden system files visible (such as `Icon` and `desktop.ini`), causing errors, as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41725115/icon-files-causing-gradle-build-fail-in-android-studio-on-os-x-using-google-driv). Rather than run scripts to delete these files, I'd like to instruct gradle  2.14 to ignore them.

In an attempt to figure out how to exclude files, I created files named "excludeme.txt" in the directories `\app\src\main\res\values` and in `\app\src\main\java\com\hfad\stopwatch\`. I unsuccessfully tried various modifications to the two `build.gradle` files in my project. None successfully excluded the file.

Specifically, I made the following modification to the `build.gradle` file for `Module: app`, per [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12617827/gradle-1-2-exclude-directory-under-resources-sourcesets/12632944#12632944):

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'], excludes: ['**/excludeme.txt'])
                                                      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12' 
}
```

I also added this to the `android` section of the same `build.gradle` file, per [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25910206/gradle-exclude-file-from-android-assets-folder/27524441):

```
aaptOptions {
    ignoreAssetsPattern "!excludeme.txt"
}
```

I also added:

```
sourceSets {
    main {
        java {
            srcDir "src"                [I also tried w/o this line]
            exclude "**/excludeme.txt"
        }
    }
}
```

When I selected `Build > Clean Project`, which triggered a build, I got this output, which shows that the file in the resources folder was not ignored:

```
Information:Gradle tasks [clean, :app:generateDebugSources, :app:mockableAndroidJar, :app:prepareDebugUnitTestDependencies, :app:generateDebugAndroidTestSources]
C:\Users\Ellen\GoogleDrive\Ellen-CS115\AndroidStudioProjects\Stopwatch\app\src\main\res\values\excludeme.txt
Error:(1, 1) Error: Premature end of file.
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugResources'.
> C:\Users\Ellen\GoogleDrive\Ellen-CS115\AndroidStudioProjects\Stopwatch\app\src\main\res\values\excludeme.txt:1:1: Error: Premature end of file.
```

The results were the same if I removed the exclamation point:

```
aaptOptions {
    ignoreAssetsPattern "!excludeme.txt"
}
```

How do I properly instruct gradle to ignore files containing a certain pattern when building Android projects?

**Update 1**

Per Stefan's suggestion below, I added the following to the `build.gradle` file for `Module: app`:

```
android {
    [omitted]
    sourceSets.main.res.exclude '**/whatever.txt'
}
```

I added a file named `whatever.txt` in the `res/layout` directory, and the build failed with:

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugResources'.
> C:\Users\Ellen\GoogleDrive\Ellen-CS115\AndroidStudioProjects\Starbuzz\app\src\main\res\layout\whatever.txt: Error: The file name must end with .xml
```

**Update 2**

Per Nathan's suggestion, I added:

```
packagingOptions {
    exclude '**/whatever.txt'
    exclude 'src/main/res/layout/whatever.txt'
}
```

to `build.gradle (Module: app)` in the `android` section. No improvement:

```
Information:Gradle tasks [:app:generateDebugSources, :app:mockableAndroidJar, :app:prepareDebugUnitTestDependencies, :app:generateDebugAndroidTestSources]
/Users/spertus/GoogleDrive/Ellen-CS115/AndroidStudioProjects/MacTest/app/src/main/res/layout/whatever.txt
Error:Error: The file name must end with .xml
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugResources'.
> /Users/spertus/GoogleDrive/Ellen-CS115/AndroidStudioProjects/MacTest/app/src/main/res/layout/whatever.txt: Error: The file name must end with .xml
Information:BUILD FAILED
```

(This last build was on a Mac, unlike the others, which were on Windows.)

Comment: The Gradle documentation on [file trees](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/working_with_files.html#sec:file_trees) may be helpful. Is there a reason to compile the fileTree in the dependency section of the build? If you will be excluding files from your build resources, use the [`sourceSet`](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.SourceSet.html) block.

Comment: Thank you. I didn't see a `sourceSet` block in any of the `build.gradle` files. I'll take a look at the documentation you cite.

Comment: If after trying a few things with `sourceSet` you run into issues, update your answer and I will see if I can help :)

Comment: I tried adding `sourceSets`, as described above. The errors all seem to be about the resource file. I'm not sure I need to exclude non *.java files from src directories; they might be ignored automatically.

Comment: @Nathan Could you take another look? I tried using `sourceSets` and added a bounty.

Comment: I have added an answer that uses the `PackagingOptions` DSL object that is Android Gradle specific.

Comment: Any luck on this? I simply cannot get exclude/excludes to work no matter what I do. Even the simplest cases fail to exclude anything.

Comment: @Diarrhio Still no solution.

Comment: @EllenSpertus I figured it out. See my answer below

Comment: This Q already existed...  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16701256/android-studio-exclude-class-from-build

Comment: @Tom That question asked about excluding certain class files.

Comment: Really good investigation! It seems aapt supports a *--ignore-assets* option, it simply excludes some asset files from final artifact. Sadly aapt doesn't support exclude any resource file, android gradle plugin can do nothing about it. I'm considering copy files out of the project before build, then copy back afterwards.

Answer (score 5):

Looks like a recent change in gradle changed the DSL for sourceSets, so you now need to specify the exclude on the filter field:

```
android {
    sourceSets.main.res.filter.exclude '**/whatever.txt'
}
```

Comment: Thank you. This isn't working for me using Gradle 3.3 in Android Studio. I don't get an error, but it does not exclude the files. What version of Gradle are you using?

Comment: Gradle 3.3, with Android plugin 2.3.0. One thing I forgot to mention is that Android Studio will *still* show the files in the Project View. However, when it comes time to compile, the files will be excluded/ignored. That didn't make solving this problem any easier ;)

Comment: I tried this in Update 1. It still doesn't work. I get the same error at `app:mergeDebugResources`.

Comment: Might be a bug. If you look at the docs (http://google.github.io/android-gradle-dsl/current/com.android.build.gradle.api.AndroidSourceSet.html) that should definitely be supported.

Answer (score 0):

The Android plugin has its own concept of SourceSets: http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide#TOC-Configuring-the-Structure

So you'll probably want to do something like

```
android {
    sourceSets.main.res.exclude '**/whatever.txt'
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but it didn't work. I got the same error when I tried putting that in my build.gradle file for the app.

Answer (score 0):

In the child project, in your case I believe it is `:APP`, add the following to the `build.gradle` file.

```
packagingOptions {
    //Exclude the file(s) in this method. Provide the path and file name.    
    exclude 'src\main\res\layout\whatever.txt' 
}
```

The [PackagingOptions DSL object](https://google.github.io/android-gradle-dsl/current/com.android.build.gradle.internal.dsl.PackagingOptions.html#com.android.build.gradle.internal.dsl.PackagingOptions:exclude(java.lang.String)) allows you to control what files are included in the `APK`. `exclude` takes a string or pattern as an argument which will allow you to ignore files or directories by name or pattern.

**EDIT**
Customizing which resources to keep from the [Android Studio docs](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/shrink-code.html).

1. Create `XML` file in your project with a `<resources>` tag.
2. Add `tools:keep="[list resources]"`
3. Add `tools:discard="[list resources]"
4. Save the file in project resources at `res/raw/keep.xml` The build will not include this file.

The end file should look similar to the one in the [Android Studio Docs](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/shrink-code.html)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:keep="@layout/l_used*_c,@layout/l_used_a,@layout/l_used_b*"
    tools:discard="@layout/unused2" />
```

Comment: Thanks. deferring lunch to test before bounty expires. :-)

Comment: Change `whatever.txt` to `whatever.xml`. Since it is in the layouts folder, Android may be expecting a .xml file. The build process for multi project builds can be a little confusing to track down what task is being executed first without explicitly ordering each one. Once you change the extension see what error message you receive.

Comment: Thanks. I made the suggested change. I now get errors parsing XML of whatever.xml, so it's still not being excluded.

Comment: Every file in the layout directory must follow be an: "XML files that define a user interface layout." Try to exclude the actual problem file and get rid of the introduced file.

Answer (score 0):

After much banging of head against keyboard, this worked for me:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'

def getCurrentFlavor() {
    Gradle gradle = getGradle()
    String tskReqStr = gradle.getStartParameter().getTaskRequests().toString()

    Pattern pattern;

    if (tskReqStr.contains("assemble"))
        pattern = Pattern.compile("assemble(\\w+)(Release|Debug)")
    else
        pattern = Pattern.compile("generate(\\w+)(Release|Debug)")

    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(tskReqStr)

    if (matcher.find())
        return matcher.group(1).toLowerCase()
    else {
        println "NO MATCH FOUND"
        return "";
    }
}

android {
.
.
.
    sourceSets {
            main {
                if (getCurrentFlavor() == 'stripped') {
                    java.exclude('**/excluded1.java',
                    .
                    .)
            }
            java {
              srcDir 'main'
            }
          }
        } 
     }
```

N.B. Credit to: 
[How to get current flavor in gradle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30621183/how-to-get-current-flavor-in-gradle) 
for writing the getCurrentFlavor method,