# android gradle:how to exclude existing translation/locale from apk?

Tags: android, gradle, locale, translation

My android app currently [contains 18 translations for 170 different strings](https://github.com/k3b/APhotoManager/issues/21) ranging from 6/170 translated to 170/170 translated.

For a non-english speaking app users it makes no sense to tell that the app is available in language xx if in fact only 3% of the strings are really translated.

My question: Is it possible to tell android-studio or gradle that i donot want language xx be included in the final apk without deleting the existing translations in the sourcetree?

i want to exclude the languages that are less than 65% translated

See also

- https://forum.f-droid.org/t/how-complete-should-a-translation-be-before-it-is-included/70
- https://forum.f-droid.org/t/translating-lots-of-app-summaries/1319/

Comment: Have a look at this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41899973/how-to-exclude-certain-files-from-android-studio-gradle-builds - it may give you some ideas

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found a way to explicitly tell which locales to support so i have to list the languages that i consider to be complete enough

```
// this does not include de=german so german is excluded from apk
android {
    defaultConfig {
        resConfigs "ar","es","fr","hi","in","it","ja","nl","pl","ro","ru","tr","uk","zz","pt-rBR","zh-rCN","zh-rTW"
    }
```

---

Unfortunately the answer from [How to exclude certain files from Android Studio gradle builds?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41899973/how-to-exclude-certain-files-from-android-studio-gradle-builds) did not work:

```
// no error but german resources are not excluded :-(
android {
    sourceSets.main.res.filter.exclude '**/res/values-de/**'
}
```

Comment: `complete enough` there is not even German in it