# Gradle duplicate entry error: META-INF/MANIFEST.MF (Or how to delete a file from jar)

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, build.gradle

I've cloned a github repository because I wanted to study the code, but when I tried to build it in Android Studio, I ran into some trouble.
After adding the google maven repository (as prompted by Android Studio) and updating both the Gradle Plugin Version and the Grade Version (to 3.5.2 and to 5.4.1, respectively), the build fails because of the following error:

> Cause: duplicate entry: META-INF/MANIFEST.MF

And this, to be more specific:

> Caused by: java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: META-INF/MANIFEST.MF

Here is my project level build.gradle file:

```
    buildscript {
        repositories {
            jcenter()
            google()
        }
    
        dependencies {
            classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.2'
    
            // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
            // in the individual module build.gradle files
        }
    }
    
    allprojects {
        repositories {
            jcenter()
    
            maven {
                url 'https://maven.google.com'
            }
    
        }
    }
```

Here's my module build.gradle file (before trying anything):

```
    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
    
    android {
        compileSdkVersion 22
        buildToolsVersion '28.0.3'
    
        defaultConfig {
            applicationId "com.thelittlenaruto.supportdesignexample"
            minSdkVersion 11
            targetSdkVersion 22
            versionCode 1
            versionName "1.0"
        }
    
        buildTypes {
            release {
                minifyEnabled false
                proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            }
        }
    }
    
    dependencies {
        implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
        implementation ('com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.1')
        implementation ('com.android.support:design:22.2.1')
        implementation 'com.github.frankiesardo:linearlistview:1.0.1@aar'
    }
```

Here's what I've tried so far:

- Adding the following to the android section of my module build.gradle file:

```
    sourceSets {
            main{
                java{
                    exclude '**/META-INF/MANIFEST'
                    exclude '**/META-INF/MANIFEST.MF'
                    exclude 'META-INF/MANIFEST'
                    exclude 'META-INF/MANIFEST.MF'
                    exclude '!META-INF/MANIFEST.MF'
                }
            }
        }
```

- Adding this:

```
    sourceSets.main.res.filter.exclude 'META-INF/MANIFEST'
        sourceSets.main.res.filter.exclude 'META-INF/MANIFEST.MF'
```

- Also this:

```
    packagingOptions {
            apply plugin: 'project-report'
            exclude '**/META-INF/MANIFEST'
            exclude '**/META-INF/MANIFEST.MF'
            exclude 'META-INF/MANIFEST'
            exclude 'META-INF/MANIFEST.MF'
            exclude '!META-INF/MANIFEST.MF'
        }
```

- And this:

```
    packagingOptions {
            pickFirst '**/META-INF/MANIFEST'
            pickFirst '**/META-INF/MANIFEST.MF'
            pickFirst 'META-INF/MANIFEST'
            pickFirst 'META-INF/MANIFEST.MF'
            pickFirst '!META-INF/MANIFEST.MF'
        }
```

- This:

```
    aaptOptions {
            ignoreAssetsPattern "!META-INF/MANIFEST.MF"
            ignoreAssetsPattern "META-INF/MANIFEST.MF"
        }
```

I think I've tried mostly everything in this question:
[How to exclude certain files from Android Studio gradle builds?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41899973/how-to-exclude-certain-files-from-android-studio-gradle-builds)

Nothing worked.

After searching for a solution, I think the problem is that I have duplicated dependencies. So I've tried the following:

```
    dependencies {
        implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
        implementation ('com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.1'){
            exclude module: 'support-v4'
        }
        implementation ('com.android.support:design:22.2.1')
        implementation 'com.github.frankiesardo:linearlistview:1.0.1@aar'
    }
```

And this:

```
    dependencies {
        implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
        implementation ('com.android.support:design:22.2.1'){
            exclude module: 'support-v7'
        }
        implementation 'com.github.frankiesardo:linearlistview:1.0.1@aar'
    }
```

I still get the same error.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I have the same problem here with my app Roboyard on GitHub:
https://stackoverflow.com/q/59130438/1069083

Maybe you find similarities there

Answer (score 19, accepted):

As [Rajen Raiyarela](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3831557/rajen-raiyarela) said, go to File->Project Structure->Project->Android Gradle Plugin Version and downgrade it from 3.5.2 to 3.5.1.

Comment: This really is not a solution.  Android Studio is nagging every time to upgrade...

Comment: This answer is obsolete, since an upgrade to gradle 3.5.3 instead seems to have fixed the problem

Answer (score 8):

Set **project dependencies** to:

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.3'
```

or latest one.

Note: by doing this, my problem has been resolved.

Comment: My problem with gradle 3.5.2 has been resolved in 3.5.3 too, but be aware: I get the warning `
Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 6.0.`

Answer (score 2):

This issue is happening because of duplicate dependencies.
Check for multiple dependencies in the Gradle app.

Comment: Correct, this is the issue. There will be duplicate dependencies in your gradle files

Comment: @Srinivasan, if there were duplicates, then it should have been resolved by either exclude or pickfirst in packagingOptions, but it issue with the Gradle plugin only. I m yet to do verify more precisely and create a sample app to regenerate the issue for adding a request in bugtracker for android studio.

Answer (score 1):

Either package it once or not at all:

```
android {
    packagingOptions {
        pickFirst "META-INF/MANIFEST.MF"
        // exclude "META-INF/MANIFEST.MF"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

as `@rubo77` says and after my confirmation:

- **Latest** solution

  - Upgrade gradle version

    - eg:

      - from `3.5.2` to `3.5.3`
      - from `3.5.2` to `3.5.4`
- *Obsolete* solution:

  - downgrade from `3.5.2` to `3.5.1`

my choice is : upgrade from `3.5.2` to `3.5.4`

`build.gradle`:

```
    dependencies {
//        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.2'
//        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.3'
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.4'
    }
```

[image: gradle 3.5.4]

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same issue in **Android Studio Giraffe**,

I delete `Build` folder and rebuild will fix the issue for me.

Go to project view -> Build

[image: Android Studio]