# Android gradle: Exclude file from external dependencies

Tags: java, android, kotlin

I added `com.eftimoff:android-pathview:1.0.8@aar` to my project but when i run app i got this error:

> Cause: duplicate entry: META-INF/MANIFEST.MF

This is `pathview` file in external libraries :

[image]

Now i want to exclude `META-INF` folder so I added this in to module gradle :

```
android {
...
    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/*'
    }
}
```

But i still got above error.

I wrote gradle script like [this suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34397796/how-to-exclude-specific-resources-from-an-aar-depedency/34525498)

When i added library like this way :
`implementation ('com.eftimoff:android-pathview:1.0.8@aar').exclude("META-INF/MANIFEST.MF")`

I got this error :

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Build file 'D:\Projects\Android\Mvvm\Kotlin\MovieDb\app\build.gradle' line: 80

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating project ':app'.
> Could not find method leftShift() for arguments [build_37vlhf9la1wtl8koroxp1kll7$_run_closure4@b32cc6a] on task ':app:excludeTask' of type org.gradle.api.DefaultTask.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

CONFIGURE FAILED in 0s
Could not find method leftShift() for arguments [build_37vlhf9la1wtl8koroxp1kll7$_run_closure4@b32cc6a] on task ':app:excludeTask' of type org.gradle.api.DefaultTask.
Open File
```

This is where `tasks.create("excludeTask") << {` i got error.
So i changed `task.create()` to this:

```
tasks.create("excludeTask")  {
    doLast{
        exclusions.each {
            File file = file("${buildDir}/intermediates/exploded-aar/${it}")
            println("Excluding file " + file)
            if (file.exists()) {
                file.delete()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And those errors gone but still i got this error again:

> Cause: duplicate entry: META-INF/MANIFEST.MF

This script seems work on `resources` and now i want to exclude a file inside a folder.

**This is complete gradle:**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'

apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'

android {

    // Enables data binding.
    dataBinding {
        enabled = true
    }

    compileSdkVersion 29
    buildToolsVersion "29.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.t.moviedb"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 29
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

//    packagingOptions {
//        exclude '/META-INF/*'
//    }
//    aaptOptions {
//        ignoreAssetsPattern "!META-INF/MANIFEST.MF"
//        ignoreAssetsPattern "META-INF/MANIFEST.MF"
//    }
}


final List<String> exclusions = [];

Dependency.metaClass.exclude = { String[] currentExclusions ->
    currentExclusions.each {
        exclusions.add("${getGroup()}/${getName()}/${getVersion()}/${it}")
    }
    return thisObject
}


dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar', '*.aar'])
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"

    // Support libraries
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.fragment:fragment:1.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'

    // Android KTX
    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.1.0'

    // Testing
    implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'

    //other
    implementation ('com.eftimoff:android-pathview:1.0.8@aar').exclude("META-INF/*")
}

tasks.create("excludeTask")  {
    doLast{
        exclusions.each {
            File file = file("${buildDir}/intermediates/exploded-aar/${it}")
            println("Excluding file " + file)
            if (file.exists()) {
                file.delete()
            }
        }
    }
}

tasks.whenTaskAdded({
    if (it.name.matches(/^process.*Resources$/)) {
        it.dependsOn excludeTask
    }
})
```

This is my gradle version:

```
\MovieDb>gradlew --version

------------------------------------------------------------
Gradle 5.4.1
------------------------------------------------------------

Build time:   2019-04-26 08:14:42 UTC
Revision:     261d171646b36a6a28d5a19a69676cd098a4c19d

Kotlin:       1.3.21
Groovy:       2.5.4
Ant:          Apache Ant(TM) version 1.9.13 compiled on July 10 2018
JVM:          1.8.0_231 (Oracle Corporation 25.231-b11)
OS:           Windows 10 10.0 amd64
```

and :

[image]

Comment: Does this not work?

    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/MANIFEST.MF'
    }

Notice that there is no leading / at the beginning of the path

Comment: I used `exclude 'META-INF/MANIFEST.MF` but i got  `Cause: duplicate entry: META-INF/MANIFEST.MF` error @DanielZolnai

Comment: Are you using Gradle Android plugin 3.5.2? If yes, can you try downgrading to 3.5.1? (Not Studio, just the plugin version)

Comment: Yes i am using gradle 3.5.2 `classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.2'` and also updated my post @DanielZolnai

Comment: Did you try downgrading to 3.5.1?

Comment: Yes and i got this errors https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/ZB8Nt72X7h/ @DanielZolnai

Comment: Remove the android-pathview-1.0.8.aar from your libs/ and try again.

Comment: Thanks bro the problem fixed . What is happen ? gradle 3.5.2 has a bug? @DanielZolnai

Comment: It seems it has, you are not the first one to report this problem: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58790393/1395437. I have added my comments as an answer so you can accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your issue was caused by multiple problems, that's why it was harder to fix.
First of all, it seems that the Gradle Android plugin version 3.5.2 has an error where you are unable to strip these extra manifest files from the apk.
As a workaround, you can revert the plugin to version `3.5.1` (not Android Studio, reverting the plugin version is enough).

Then you saw the error:

> Cause: duplicate entry: META-INF/MANIFEST.MF

This was because you have temporarily removed the part

```
packagingOptions {
    exclude 'META-INF/MANIFEST.MF'
}
```

From you build.gradle, because it did not work because of the plugin bug.
Finally, you saw the error:

> Duplicate class com.caverock.androidsvg.CSSParser found in modules androidsvg-1.2.1.jar (android-pathview-1.0.8.aar) and androidsvg-1.2.1.jar (com.eftimoff:android-pathview:1.0.8)

This was because you have included a modified library in your `libs/` folder, but forgot to remove it from your `implementation {}` section, so it was included two times.