# update the Android Gradle plugin from the current version 3.4.1 to version 3.5.2 and Gradle to version 5.4.1 fails

Tags: java, android, android-studio, gradle

When I load the project Roboyard Version 9.0 into Android Studio, building works fine, but A.S. suggests to upgrade Gradle. When I do so, I cannot build the App any more, I get the error

```
Execution failed for task ':app:javaPreCompileDebug'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugCompileClasspath'.
   > Failed to transform artifact 'support-v4.aar (com.android.support:support-v4:21.0.2)' to match attributes {artifactType=android-classes, org.gradle.usage=java-api}.
      > Execution failed for AarToClassTransform: /home/ruben/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/com.android.support/support-v4/21.0.2/39eadabc45185963eaec97aae33466fb5a40e9a/support-v4-21.0.2.aar.
         > duplicate entry: META-INF/MANIFEST.MF
```

If I go to File > Project Structure... > Project > Android Gradle Plugin Version and downgrade it from 3.5.2 to 3.5.1. The buid still works perfectly without error, (but I get the upgrade suggestion again).

So there seems to be something odd in the latest gradle version 3.5.2?

Comment: I have the same issue.

Comment: @farrukhNajmi please report here, if you find a solution

Comment: Note: this problem is fixed in gradle 3.5.3

Comment: @rubo77 i still get the same problem with 3.5.3